# Facebook Send Requests

Tags: facebook

How are we supposed to [send requests on Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/) if [Facebook is in the process of deprecating FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml)? Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! (Well, I didn't, but my friend did.)

[Facebook Requests Dialog - JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Facebook was hiding it! :)

It's really cool. Much better than old requests. You can store custom data in them and access it through the Graph API!

Note to self: "Read the documentation thoroughly."

Comment: It was not really hidden :-) It's brand new and announced on January 27 : http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/453

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no other way..Facebook is updating the graph api and message part.So you can use FBML itself for the current use.You can use [request-form](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form) and [multi-friend-selecto](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/) to send the request.

```
<fb:request-form 
action="start.htm" 
method="POST" 
invite="true" 
type="sample network" 
content="This network is the best place on Facebook for viewing, sharing and giving 
         friends the highest quality stuff.  Join me on this network!
     <fb:req-choice url='http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=<c:out value='${apiKey}' />' 
         label='Check out this network!' />
">

<fb:multi-friend-selector 
    showborder="false" 
    actiontext="Invite your friends to this network."
    exclude_ids="<c:out value='${appUserFriends}' />" 
    max="20" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but since Facebook is in the process of deprecating this, I don't recommend doing this because it probably wont work for long. I think the new way is to just send emails to the users. Unfortunately, we can only send emails to app users who've given us the email permission. Perhaps another option is to make private wall posts.

Comment: Ya I know that.But as Bartek said it will take some for FBML.So continue with this for time sake .

Answer (score 1):

According to [this part](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas#requests) of the documentation it will be possible to achieve through dialogues.

> Please note, we are in the process of moving this functionality to Platform Dialogs which will remove the requirement for the use of FBML.

At the moment I couldn't find anything about inviting friends yet (*Friend Dialog* is misleading - it's about adding new friends) but I suggest you keep an eye on updates [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/).

I would say use FBML for now because it will take some time before it is officially deprecated (it was announced a long time ago) but check up on the new methods so that you can implement it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

And there is the option of the send button as a tag
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/
This is not deprecated right???